# Две библиотеки требуют третью, разных версий

Tags: php, composer

Хочу установить `googleads/googleads-php-lib` но в процессе установки выясняется что ей нужна `guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.0`, ок, обновляю guzzle, выясняется что уже есть библиотека которая требует `guzzlehttp/guzzle ~5.1`. 
Что делать в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно подойдет версия 19.0.0 (https://packagist.org/packages/googleads/googleads-php-lib#19.0.0).

Там не используется guzzlehttp/guzzle.